# Missing some files when jar file is transformed in c# in Visual Studio with Xamarin

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, jar

I am very new to develop applications and writing in English as well...

I am trying to use jar file with Visual Studio2017 + Xamarin.

Currently, the problem I am facing is, when I put a jar file into Binding Library Project(Android) and build it, many files which supposed to be generated as c# are missing.

For example, when I have 3 files named "example1.class", "example2.class", "example3.class" in a jar file, only "example1.cs" is generated and "example2.cs", "example3.cs" are not genereted.
so I can not use this jar file at all.

What could be a problem?

the link where I got the jar file (SDK) is [here](https://github.com/imobile-maio/maio-Android-SDK).

I will appreciate any comments.

Comment: In addition, I did not encounter any error when building the binding library project.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb

Comment: @SushiHangover 
I appreciate your comment. 
The problem has been solved.
I think the cause was that the jar file contained lots of classes which had characteristics of obfuscation, like _a.class_ .

When I checked the setting of AndroidClassParser, it was originally **class-parse** . Then, **I tried to change it to jar2xml and build it, and change back to class-parse again** then this problem was resolved.